# how to show all x label charts ios?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I make a custom numbering label, everything works great. the problem is when the number of entries is less than X-axis maximum, the chart doesn't show any lines.

```
    lineChart.data = data

    let leftAxis = lineChart.leftAxis
    
    //set constant label range
    leftAxis.forceLabelsEnabled = true
    leftAxis.labelCount = 4
    
    leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    leftAxis.axisMaximum = 4.5
   
    leftAxis.granularity = 1
    leftAxis.axisLineWidth = 0
    leftAxis.valueFormatter = YAxisData()

    
    //x axis label
    let bottomAxis = lineChart.xAxis
    bottomAxis.axisMinimum = 1
    bottomAxis.axisMaximum = 7.0
    
    bottomAxis.labelCount = 7
    bottomAxis.forceLabelsEnabled = true
    
    bottomAxis.granularity = 1

    bottomAxis.axisLineWidth = 0
    bottomAxis.valueFormatter = XAxisData()
    bottomAxis.labelHeight = 30
```

[image]

if I changed the number of entries to 7, it works fine.
I want a way to show all x labels even if the number of entries is less than 7!

Comment: Can't you make it dynamic and pass the number of entries and use that values instead of hardcoding 7?

Comment: It work if i make it dynamic. The problem is that x-axis is week days so i have to show all of them.

Comment: Then create some kind of static empty entry and add it where entries are missing so you always have seven of them

Comment: I don't know how to assign an empty entries. as the entries are Double values!

Comment: Then isn't zero an empty value?

Comment: No, as these strings and emoji are a representation of numbers. So when I assign any numeric value , it would be represented on the chart

Comment: Well I don't have anymore suggestions